# Action.php Fatal error in calling admin page

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, fatal-error

When I call my admin page (http://www.soundundlight.de/shop/index.php/admin), I get the following error message:

> *Fatal error: Call to a member function addLink() on a non-object in /www/htdocs/w012a4c9/soundundlight.de/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
>   on line 113*

```
.../shop/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
```

**Action.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Adminhtml
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006-2014 X.commerce, Inc. (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

/**
 * Base adminhtml controller
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Adminhtml
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action extends Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action
{
    /**
     * Name of "is URLs checked" flag
     */
    const FLAG_IS_URLS_CHECKED = 'check_url_settings';

    /**
     * Session namespace to refer in other places
     */
    const SESSION_NAMESPACE = 'adminhtml';

    /**
     * Array of actions which can be processed without secret key validation
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_publicActions = array();

    /**
     * Used module name in current adminhtml controller
     */
    protected $_usedModuleName = 'adminhtml';

    /**
     * Currently used area
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_currentArea = 'adminhtml';

    /**
     * Namespace for session.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_sessionNamespace = self::SESSION_NAMESPACE;

    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve adminhtml session model object
     *
     * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Session
     */
    protected function _getSession()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve base admihtml helper
     *
     * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Helper_Data
     */
    protected function _getHelper()
    {
        return Mage::helper('adminhtml');
    }

    /**
     * Define active menu item in menu block
     *
     * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
     */
    protected function _setActiveMenu($menuPath)
    {
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('menu')->setActive($menuPath);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
     */
    protected function _addBreadcrumb($label, $title, $link=null)
    {
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')->addLink($label, $title, $link);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
     */
    protected function _addContent(Mage_Core_Block_Abstract $block)
    {
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
        return $this;
    }

    protected function _addLeft(Mage_Core_Block_Abstract $block)
    {
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('left')->append($block);
        return $this;
    }

    protected function _addJs(Mage_Core_Block_Abstract $block)
    {
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('js')->append($block);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Controller predispatch method
     *
     * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
     */
    public function preDispatch()
    {
        // override admin store design settings via stores section
        Mage::getDesign()
            ->setArea($this->_currentArea)
            ->setPackageName((string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode('stores/admin/design/package/name'))
            ->setTheme((string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode('stores/admin/design/theme/default'))
        ;
        foreach (array('layout', 'template', 'skin', 'locale') as $type) {
            if ($value = (string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode("stores/admin/design/theme/{$type}")) {
                Mage::getDesign()->setTheme($type, $value);
            }
        }

        $this->getLayout()->setArea($this->_currentArea);

        Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_controller_action_predispatch_start', array());
        parent::preDispatch();
        $_isValidFormKey = true;
        $_isValidSecretKey = true;
        $_keyErrorMsg = '';
        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
            if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
                $_isValidFormKey = $this->_validateFormKey();
                $_keyErrorMsg = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.');
            } elseif (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->useSecretKey()) {
                $_isValidSecretKey = $this->_validateSecretKey();
                $_keyErrorMsg = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Invalid Secret Key. Please refresh the page.');
            }
        }
        if (!$_isValidFormKey || !$_isValidSecretKey) {
            $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
            $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_POST_DISPATCH, true);
            if ($this->getRequest()->getQuery('isAjax', false) || $this->getRequest()->getQuery('ajax', false)) {
                $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode(array(
                    'error' => true,
                    'message' => $_keyErrorMsg
                )));
            } else {
                $this->_redirect( Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getStartupPageUrl() );
            }
            return $this;
        }

        if ($this->getRequest()->isDispatched()
            && $this->getRequest()->getActionName() !== 'denied'
            && !$this->_isAllowed()) {
            $this->_forward('denied');
            $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
            return $this;
        }

        if (!$this->getFlag('', self::FLAG_IS_URLS_CHECKED)
            && !$this->getRequest()->getParam('forwarded')
            && !$this->_getSession()->getIsUrlNotice(true)
            && !Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/can_use_base_url')) {
            //$this->_checkUrlSettings();
            $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_IS_URLS_CHECKED, true);
        }
        if (is_null(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getLocale())) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setLocale(Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode());
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @deprecated after 1.4.0.0 alpha, logic moved to Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Notification_Baseurl
     * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
     */
    protected function _checkUrlSettings()
    {
        /**
         * Don't check for data saving actions
         */
        if ($this->getRequest()->getPost() || $this->getRequest()->getQuery('isAjax')) {
            return $this;
        }

        $configData = Mage::getModel('core/config_data');

        $defaultUnsecure = (string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode(
            'default/' . Mage_Core_Model_Store::XML_PATH_UNSECURE_BASE_URL
        );
        $defaultSecure = (string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode(
            'default/' . Mage_Core_Model_Store::XML_PATH_SECURE_BASE_URL
        );

        if ($defaultSecure == '{{base_url}}' || $defaultUnsecure == '{{base_url}}') {
            $this->_getSession()->addNotice(
                $this->__('{{base_url}} is not recommended to use in a production environment to declare the Base Unsecure URL / Base Secure URL. It is highly recommended to change this value in your Magento <a href="%s">configuration</a>.', $this->getUrl('adminhtml/system_config/edit', array('section'=>'web')))
            );
            return $this;
        }

        $dataCollection = $configData->getCollection()
            ->addValueFilter('{{base_url}}');

        $url = false;
        foreach ($dataCollection as $data) {
            if ($data->getScope() == 'stores') {
                $code = Mage::app()->getStore($data->getScopeId())->getCode();
                $url = $this->getUrl('adminhtml/system_config/edit', array('section'=>'web', 'store'=>$code));
            }
            if ($data->getScope() == 'websites') {
                $code = Mage::app()->getWebsite($data->getScopeId())->getCode();
                $url = $this->getUrl('adminhtml/system_config/edit', array('section'=>'web', 'website'=>$code));
            }

            if ($url) {
                $this->_getSession()->addNotice(
                    $this->__('{{base_url}} is not recommended to use in a production environment to declare the Base Unsecure URL / Base Secure URL. It is highly recommended to change this value in your Magento <a href="%s">configuration</a>.', $url)
                );
                return $this;
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function deniedAction()
    {
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.1','403 Forbidden');
        if (!Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->_redirect('*/index/login');
            return;
        }
        $this->loadLayout(array('default', 'adminhtml_denied'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function loadLayout($ids=null, $generateBlocks=true, $generateXml=true)
    {
        parent::loadLayout($ids, $generateBlocks, $generateXml);
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('adminhtml/session');
        return $this;
    }

    public function norouteAction($coreRoute = null)
    {
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.1','404 Not Found');
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Status','404 File not found');
        $this->loadLayout(array('default', 'adminhtml_noroute'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }


    /**
     * Retrieve currently used module name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUsedModuleName()
    {
        return $this->_usedModuleName;
    }

    /**
     * Set currently used module name
     *
     * @param string $moduleName
     * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
     */
    public function setUsedModuleName($moduleName)
    {
        $this->_usedModuleName = $moduleName;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Translate a phrase
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function __()
    {
        $args = func_get_args();
        $expr = new Mage_Core_Model_Translate_Expr(array_shift($args), $this->getUsedModuleName());
        array_unshift($args, $expr);
        return Mage::app()->getTranslator()->translate($args);
    }

    /**
     * Set referer url for redirect in responce
     *
     * Is overriden here to set defaultUrl to admin url
     *
     * @param   string $defaultUrl
     * @return  Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
     */
    protected function _redirectReferer($defaultUrl=null)
    {
        $defaultUrl = empty($defaultUrl) ? $this->getUrl('*') : $defaultUrl;
        parent::_redirectReferer($defaultUrl);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set redirect into responce
     *
     * @param   string $path
     * @param   array $arguments
     */
    protected function _redirect($path, $arguments=array())
    {
        $this->_getSession()->setIsUrlNotice($this->getFlag('', self::FLAG_IS_URLS_CHECKED));
        $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($this->getUrl($path, $arguments));
        return $this;
    }

    protected function _forward($action, $controller = null, $module = null, array $params = null)
    {
        $this->_getSession()->setIsUrlNotice($this->getFlag('', self::FLAG_IS_URLS_CHECKED));
        return parent::_forward($action, $controller, $module, $params);
    }

    /**
     * Generate url by route and parameters
     *
     * @param   string $route
     * @param   array $params
     * @return  string
     */
    public function getUrl($route='', $params=array())
    {
        return Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl($route, $params);
    }

    /**
     * Validate Secret Key
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _validateSecretKey()
    {
        if (is_array($this->_publicActions) && in_array($this->getRequest()->getActionName(), $this->_publicActions)) {
            return true;
        }

        if (!($secretKey = $this->getRequest()->getParam(Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Url::SECRET_KEY_PARAM_NAME, null))
            || $secretKey != Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->getSecretKey()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Validate password for current admin user
     *
     * @param string $password - current password
     *
     * @return mixed - returns true or array of errors
     */
    protected function _validateCurrentPassword($password)
    {
        $user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser();
        return $user->validateCurrentPassword($password);
    }
}
```

Please tell me anyone what is wrong?

Comment: Is this a clean installation? Did you change anything to the code?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your fast answer. This is not a new installation. I have not changed the code, but I made an update. After that I got a lot of errors, see here (http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60188/many-problems-after-update). Then I uploaded the whole FTP and now get this error. The cache I have already been deleted, but the result is the same.

Comment: did you update the app/design/adminhtml folder also?

Comment: Maybe, I do not know exactly. I have made at all an update on what the downloader has proposed.

Comment: So you did make changes to the code, because you upgraded your installation. Didn't you test this on a local environment first?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I had thought that the method via the downloader is safe. I'm an idiot, I know. Now I'm smarter. But now I have to try it to work again.

Comment: ok Jens. Try out the following:
- download latest source from magento website
- backup content of your app/design/adminhtml/default/default folder
- replace the content of  app/design/adminhtml/default/default with correspondent folder from magento website.
- clean cache
BTW. From which version you upgraded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out the following:

- download latest source from magento website
- backup content of your app/design/adminhtml/default/default folder
- replace the content of  app/design/adminhtml/default/default with correspondent folder from magento website.
- clean cache

Comment: That works! Thank you!!! Very nice, you're my hero.